# Moving windows doesn't feel smooth

Tags: drivers, screen

Recently i installed Ubuntu as the main OS after windows 10 and in noticed that while moving
opened windows doesn't feel smooth and there is a delay when the pixels moves.
I didn't install any drivers in my device, how can i install my drivers?
my laptop model is lenovo ideapad 520

Comment: Gnome, which Ubuntu uses, is heavy on resources. Try xfce with compton as a compositor.

Answer (score 0):

If you have low end pc then switch the desktop environment as genome and unity both (default desktop) are bit heavy. you can install lightweight desktop environment like

- xfce
- mate
- openbox
- lxde
- i3

If you have good pc or this is the first time you face the issue with same hardware then you might try to check the extensions you have installed and the window manager. And also make sure that your pc is not over heating(surprisingly this bring a lot of issue ) and if you are using external monitor then check for quality of the wire and the port. Also don't forget to keep drivers updated. If you have done any tweak to xorg(or other display related configuration that you are not sure about) reverse it. Also check for your current screen refresh rate(this plays vital role), if you think that is too low than your pc is capable of handeling then set it to higher value by

```
xrandr --output DVI-D-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 60.00
```

or any other value you want ( 1920x1080 is screen resolution and 60.0 is screen refresh rate )